# Django - User inherited IntegrityError

Tags: python, mysql, django, inheritance, django-models

I'm trying to use the [User profile](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) feature so here is my profile model:

```
class Nuser(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User)
  initials = models.CharField(max_length=5)
  def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Nuser.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

My models are correctly created but if I try to add a user with the admin interface I get this error:

> IntegrityError at /admin/auth/user/add/
>
> (1062, "Duplicate entry '3' for key 'user_id'")

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: One user can only have one user profile. Can you paste the data in your `User` and `UserProfile` tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signal is probably being registered more than once. Use the [`dispatch_uid` argument](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#preventing-duplicate-signals) to prevent this.

For example:

```
post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User, dispatch_uid='autocreate_nuser')
```